# C++ data structures instead of database

Tags: c++, database, data-structures, vector, struct

I have written a C++ program that using database with 5 tables(and thousands of row). But there is performance issue in that approach. Now, I will try to use C++ data types and functions for that. Which one is best for that situation. I am considering to use struct in vectors. Also I can use libraries for that if exists. Can they solve my problem?

By the way my DB is PostgreSQL.

Comment: (Since you are a fan of the unspecific;) Yes.

Comment: You may use serialization as another alternative

Comment: A vector of structs certainly bears a close resemblance to a database. Whether it's close *enough* to a database to suit your task without huge amounts of work will probably depend heavily on what you're doing with the data (especially how you're retrieving it).

Comment: As databases are designed and optimised to work with a lot of data, could it just be that you need to restructure your database with more tables and normalisation to get the performance you want? If you provide more detail about the data and tables that you have, you'd likely get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Berkeley DB, it is a popular embedded database that has good performance.

Latest versions offer a SQL-like API, this can simplify the migration of your code from your a classical SQL database.

However, be careful of the license terms of this library. It is available in both a GPL-like license and commercial license (i.e. no LGLP-like license is available). Depending of your application (and your wallet), this may be an issue.